# Interpreting the fitted model outputs from a covariate-adjusted ROC curve in the AROC package

Tags: r, roc, epidemiology

Below I have fitted a covariate-adjusted ROC curve (AROC) using a semiparametric Bayesian normal linear regression model available in the R package “AROC”. However, I am not clear on how to interpret/report the results of the fitting process.

```
library(AROC)
data(psa)
# Select the last measurement
newpsa <- psa[!duplicated(psa$id, fromLast = TRUE),]

marker1aauc <- AROC.sp(formula.healthy = "marker1 ~ age", 
          group = "status", 
          tag.healthy = 0, 
          data = newpsa)

summary(marker1aauc$fit.h)
```

**Fitted model outputs**

Residuals:

| Min | 1Q | Median | 3Q | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.397 | -1.724 | -0.647 | 0.458 | 33.454 |

Coefficients:

| Variable | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | Pr(>t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | -12.9464 | 7.1945 | -1.799 | 0.0764 |
| age | 0.2255 | 0.1049 | 2.149 | 0.0352 |

Residual standard error: 4.493 on 68 degrees of freedom 
Multiple R-squared: 0.06361, Adjusted R-squared: 0.04984 
F-statistic: 4.619 on 1 and 68 DF, p-value: 0.03518

**Specific questions**

What is the unit used in the residuals and β coefficients?

Is it correct to say that the predictive accuracy of marker1 was worse for those who were older (β = 0.2255 per 1-year increase, p-value = 0.0352)?

Is the multiple R-squared value interpreted as the covariates in the model (i.e. age) accounted for approximately 6% of the predictive accuracy of marker1 (multiple R-squared = 0.06361)?

Does the F-statistic p-value at the end refer to the multiple-R-squared and adjusted R-squared (i.e. multiple R-squared = 0.06361, p-value = 0.03518)?

Is the term "multiple R squared" correct here since only age (one covariate) is adjusted for, or should it be just "R squared"?